# AWS ApiGateway customize Request Validation Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, aws-api-gateway

I have configured my AWS APIGateway to validate the requests according to a JSON schema.

E.g. the path /vehicle, which has the following schema attached:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "licensePlate":{
         "pattern":"[A-Za-z]{1,3} [A-Za-z]{1,2} \\d{1,4}",
         "type":"string"
      },
      "vehicleType":{
         "type":"string",
         "enum":[
            "Truck",
            "Trailer"
         ]
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "licensePlate",
      "vehicleType"
   ]
}
```

This works fine. If I submit an invalid request the API responds with a 400 `{"message": "Invalid request body"}`. I would like to customize this message, e.g. to

```
{
  "entity": "vehicleType",
  "message": "missing"
}
```

If I take a look at the logs from the Gateway it seems that a similar message is logged (`object has missing required properties (["vehicleType"])`). Can I use that one? How can I access it?

Logs:

```
Execution log for request test-request
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /vehicle
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Method request path: {}
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Method request query string: {}
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Method request body before transformations: {
    "licensePlate": "HH AB 123"
}
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Request body does not match model schema for content type application/json: [object has missing required properties (["vehicleType"])] 
Thu Feb 01 13:12:18 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 400
```

Is this possible with the API Gateway?

Comment: did you find how to get that messages?

Answer (score 8):

Yeah what you want is the [$context.error.validationErrorString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference)

Like @Bajwa said -- you need to customize the GatewayReponse template. If you're using cloud formation that looks like this:

```
"GatewayResponse": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse",
  "Properties": {
    "ResponseParameters": {
      "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
      "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'"
    },
    "ResponseTemplates": {
      "application/json": "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"$context.error.messageString\",\"errors\":\"$context.error.validationErrorString\"}"
    },
    "ResponseType": "BAD_REQUEST_BODY",
    "RestApiId": {
      "Ref": "YouRestApiResource"
    },
    "StatusCode": "400"
  }
}
```

If you violate the request body validator you'll see something like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message":" "Invalid request body"",
    "errors":"[string \"1\" is too short (length: 1, required minimum: 10)]"
}
```

It's not perfect -- some of the messaging is vague, would be nice if anyone knows how to for example add the property name that caused the violation.

Answer (score 4):

If the request payload is invalid, you will see the same message:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request body"
}
```

API Gateway includes more detail, if the request payload format is valid and parameters format is invalid.

See more detail from below link, especially the bottom part.

[Test Basic Request Validation in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-test.html)

But you may do some customization in the response message by customizing Gateway responses.
You may customize `Bad Request Body 400`.

```
{
    "message":"$context.error.messageString", 
    "Hint":"Check required number of parameters or parameters allowed type and length."
}
```

Then you will see message in below format.

```
{
    "message": "Invalid request body",
    "Hint": "Check required number of parameters or parameters allowed type and length."
}
```

See hot to update Body Mapping Template from attached screenshot. (APIGateway/Gateway Responses).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This might go in the right direction. Instead of the static `hint` property I would like to include the real property, which failed to validate. If you have a look at my API Gateway log example from above: I'm talking about the property `vehicleType`. But I guess this is not possible right now?!

Comment: can we add real property which failed to validate?Even I am facing the same issue..